# Show/hide dynamic content with data attributes

Tags: jquery, html

I am struggling with achieving a

My html code is:

```
<div id="menu"></div>

<ul class="countries">
<li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
<li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
<li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
<li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
<li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
<li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
<li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
<li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
<li data-country="country-3" data-countryname="Germany">Category Germany</li>
</ul>
```

My JS code:

```
 var countries = {},
 country;
 $('.countries li[data-country]').each(function (i, el) {
     country = $(el).data('country');
     countryname = $(el).data('countryname');
     if (countries.hasOwnProperty(country)) {
         countries[country] += 1;
     } else {
         countries[country] = 1;
     }
 });

 for (var key in countries) {
     $('#menu').append('<span data-countrycode="' + key + '">' + key + ' (' + countries[key] + ')</span>');
 }

 $('#menu span').click(function () {
     var clicked = $(this).data('countrycode');
     $('li[data-country=' + clicked + ']').show(1000).siblings().hide(1000);
 });
```

The JS code above builds a menu with Country Code - **Q1) How can I display Country Name instead?**

Also the toggle - hide/show function isn't working properly- **Q2) Is there a way how to filter/display the content by Country Code**

And the very last question - **Q3) Is it possible to alphabetically order all list items by the second word without using any of data attributes?**

Please see my JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/oja417nq/2/

Many thanks...

Comment: do you want to sort the li's by its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1) How can I display Country Name instead?**

I've replaced all the `countrycode` references to `countryname`.

**Q2) Is there a way how to filter/display the content by Country Code?**

You were hiding siblings. I've made a `$().not()` selector to hide the ones that don't match with the clicked.

**Q3) Is it possible to alphabetically order all list items by the second word without using any of data attributes?**

Let's do a small sort function then:

```
var $list = $(".countries");

$list.children().detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().split(' ')[1].localeCompare($(b).text().split(' ')[1]);
}).appendTo($list);
```

We select only the 2 word with `.text().split(' ')[1]` and we do a `$.sort()`.

**Full snippet:**

```js
var countries = {},
  country;
$('.countries li[data-country]').each(function(i, el) {
  country = $(el).data('country');
  countryname = $(el).data('countryname');
  if (countries.hasOwnProperty(countryname)) {
    countries[countryname] += 1;
  } else {
    countries[countryname] = 1;
  }
});

for (var key in countries) {
  $('#menu').append('<span data-countrycode="' + key + '">' + key + ' (' + countries[key] + ')</span>');
}

var $list = $(".countries");

$list.children().detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().split(' ')[1].localeCompare($(b).text().split(' ')[1]);
}).appendTo($list);


$('#menu span').click(function() {
  var clicked = $(this).data('countrycode');
  $('li[data-countryname=' + clicked + ']').show(1000);
  $('li').not('[data-countryname=' + clicked + ']').hide(200);
});
```

```css
#menu span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"></div>

<ul class="countries">
   <li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
   <li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
   <li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
   <li data-country="country-3" data-countryname="Germany">Category Germany</li>
   <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category Alpha</li>
   <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category Beta</li>
   <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category C</li>
   <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category D</li>
   <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category E</li>
</ul>
```

Regarding your question 3, you need probably to manipulate the list and make a sort function on it. But I'm not sure of what you desire.

Comment: Thank you Joel. Can you help me achieve a result on my Q3) Is it possible to alphabetically order all list items by the second word without using any of data attributes? Really appreciate your help

Comment: @qqruza The second word ? Like `category UK`, being the second word `UK` ? also, are you sure its always two words? or is there more?

Comment: Yes please. The idea behind it it maybe a person name instead of Country UK like John Doe and I want to alphabetically order them by Surname (second name)

Comment: @Joel_Almeida you are a fantastic developer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```js
var countries = {};
$('.countries li[data-country]').each(function(i, el) {
  var country = $(el).data('country');
  if (!countries[country]) {
    countries[country] = {
      count: 0,
      name: $(el).data('countryname')
    };
  }
  countries[country].count++;
});

for (var key in countries) {
  $('#menu').append('<span data-countrycode="' + key + '">' + countries[key].name + ' (' + countries[key].count + ')</span>');
}

$('#menu span').click(function() {
  var clicked = $(this).data('countrycode');
  var $els = $('li[data-country=' + clicked + ']').show(1000);
  $('.countries > li').not($els).hide(1000);
});
```

```css
#menu span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"></div>
<ul class="countries">
  <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
  <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
  <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
  <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
  <li data-country="country-1" data-countryname="France">Category France</li>
  <li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
  <li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
  <li data-country="country-2" data-countryname="UK">Category UK</li>
  <li data-country="country-3" data-countryname="Germany">Category Germany</li>
</ul>
```